# How to specify the function-attribute general-regs-only

Tags: c++, gcc

I wanted to get rid of the compiler warning `warning: FP registers might be clobbered despite 'isr' attribute: compile with '-mgeneral-regs-only' [-Wattributes]`, so I tried to add the function attribute `general-regs-only`.

But `g++` does not accept this attribute:

```
void SysTick_Handler() __attribute__ ((isr, general-regs-only));
```

gives `error: expected ')' before '-' token 49 | void SysTick_Handler() __attribute__ ((isr, general-regs-only));`

Answer (score 0):

From the [attribute syntax section](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Attribute-Syntax.html) in the GCC documentation, it says that attribute names

> ... may be an identifier such as `unused`, or a reserved word such as `const`

That means attribute names can't contain dashes, just like no other identifier may.

This means the GCC documentation contains an error when it documents the `general-regs-only` attribute, because that's not a valid identifier name.

You need to be using `general_regs_only` instead.

<sub>[Please note that I haven't be able to test this]</sub>

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat a workaround, but have you tried using pragmas instead? E.g. this way:

```c
#pragma GCC push_options
#pragma GCC target("general-regs-only")
void foo() __attribute__((isr));
#pragma GCC pop_options
```

https://godbolt.org/z/zesqzsrGK

BTW, what platform are you programming for and do you actually need that attribute? In some cases it's not necessary, e.g.: [__attribute__((interrupt)) for exception handler in GCC (ARM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22419780/attribute-interrupt-for-exception-handler-in-gcc-arm)

Comment: The workaround looks ok, thank you!

Comment: I am programming for Cortex-M4+FPU (STM32G431)